# Why can't I close a question for migration?

Tags: support, migration

I've just tried to close [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243558/can-i-have-your-point-of-view-opinion-on-the-homonyms-and-homophones-right-and) for obvious reasons. At first (since this is clearly destined for the English Stack Exchange) I tried to use Close -> Off-topic -> Migration to close the question and recommend it be sent to english.stackexchange.com. However, the only option for me is to send it here, to Meta. Which is clearly not appropriate. I also thought of using the "Blatantly Off-topic (this question has nothing to do with gaming)" option, but apparently that has been removed at some point, or it's not appearing for me. The only option I had left was to leave a comment telling the asker to go to English Stack Exchange. It left me with this question though; why can't I recommend sending the question to sites other than Meta?

Comment: Because migration of crap should not happen. That question is the epitome of such.

Comment: @imulsion - We'd need to set up a custom migration path, which only happens if we're constantly dealing with questions that should be on a particular sister site. Seeing as we've only had one question worth migrating to ELU OR ELL, the mods can handle this exception

Comment: @Robotnik Seems sensible. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Several months ago, we had the option of migration. However, my understanding is that this was mostly used poorly. Questions would be dubbed suitable for other SE sites based off the context, alone. As a result, there were complaints that most of the questions we migrated were still not appropriate for the new SE sites. We were effectively migrating crap, as Frank puts it.

Since then, only Arqade Meta has remained an option for migration. If you truly believe the question is suitable for the intended exchange site, simply provide a link to it in your close reason. This points OP in the right direction, but does not automatically push this poor-quality to one of our sister sites.

In this case, you have effectively done so. For the purpose of helping, I prefer to provide a reason behind it. Some users tend to reply with "Screw you why wont you help me", when we are effectively trying to usher them towards a much more suitable audience. Given OPs obvious skill level regarding english, elaborating more then you have done would probably have been pointless.